# I am trying to take a char out of a string

Tags: c#, string, char

I need help here. What do I do wrong when trying to take out the second char from the string?

```
// read in a string from the user in the following format:
//pyramid slot number, block letter, whether or not the block should be lit
Console.Write("Enter slot number, block letter & if the block should be lit or not (y/n)");
string csvString = Console.ReadLine();

// find comma location
int commaLocation = csvString.IndexOf(',');

// extract slot number
int slotnumber = int.Parse(csvString.Substring(0,commaLocation));

// Print slot number
Console.WriteLine("Slot number: " + slotnumber);

// extract block letter
*string blockletter = string.ConvertToChar(csvString.Substring(commaLocation + 1));*
           // print block letter
Console.WriteLine("Block letter: " + blockletter);
```

Comment: U must be confused in ascii value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split()` to separate a string into a list of words/characters.

```
List<string> charactersSplit = csvString.Split(",");
string slotNumber = charactersSplit[0];
string blockLetter = charactersSplit[1];
```

Comment: The professor means that we shouldn't use string but char. There is where the problem occure :-) Thank you for you help and interest